# hero slider image not showing full width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to have the image on my slider display full width inside the container. I have tried separating the hero-text div but it still does not work. Ive been stuck on this for ages and realise its probably something stupid so stack overflow is my last resort. Please see below for code and image of how it displays:

[Display Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdXjd.png)

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
/* HERO IMAGE STARTS */
.hero-image {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8));
  height: 500px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.hero-text {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
}

.hero-text h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.hero-text .button {
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 14px 30px !important;
}

/* BLOCKS STARTS */
.border-bottom {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dee2e6 !important;
}

.no-gutters {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.padding-5 {
  padding: 3rem !important;
}

.height-100 {
  height: 100% !important;
}

.width-100 {
  width: 100% !important;
}

.bg-light {
  background-color: #f8f9fa !important;
}

.display-block {
  display: block !important;
}

.marginbottom-3 {
  margin-bottom: 1rem !important;
}

.block-feature h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.block-feature h2::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 50px;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #763797;
  left: 0;
}

display-4 {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #763797;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

```html
!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>GloboGym</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/foundation.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/app.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/fonts/flaticon/font/flaticon.css">
</head>

<body>

  <!-- HERO AREA STARTS -->
  <section>
    <div class="hero-image">
      <div class="hero-text mySlides fade" style="background-image: url(assets/img/banner-bg.jpg);">
        <h1>From Only £14.99 A Month, Everybody Is Welcome</h1>
        <a href="membership.html" class="button">Join Now</a>
      </div>
      <div class="hero-text mySlides fade" style="background-image: url(assets/img/banner-bg1.jpg);">
        <h1>From Only £14.99 A Month, Everybody Is Welcome</h1>
        <a href="membership.html" class="button">Join Now</a>
      </div>
      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- HERO AREA ENDS -->
  <script src="assets/js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/vendor/what-input.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/vendor/foundation.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/vendor/globogym-scrips.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not able to run the snippet that you provided.

Comment: strange, i have updated it but it still doesn't show correct. See image for reference

Comment: Hi I posted the answer after looking at the image you posted. Let me know if it is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

From the screenshot you posted. Problem is with your css. You have given the background-size: cover to the container and not to the image inside. That's why it is not going to take up the whole space. You need the following code for your image to take up the whole space of the container.

In CSS :

```
.mySlides { background-size: cover ; height : 500px; }
```

Comment: Yes this is very helpful, i had to make a few adjustments but i have now achieved what i was after. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah also my suggestion would be for height better use relative height so it is scalable along with media queries.